# SelectedValue binding does not write write back

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listbox, selectedvalue

I'm new to wpf. Trying to add a listbox in a datagrid. Everything runs perfect but the selected value binding is not working. It's not writing the SelectedValue back. Please help.

```
<DataGrid Name="SoruDataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Test.TestSonucuCollection}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Soru.Id}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Soru" Binding="{Binding Soru.Text}" Width="300">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cevap">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Soru.CevapCollection}" 
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Text" 
                                 SelectedValuePath="{Binding Id}"
                                 SelectedValue="{Binding CevapId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
```

CevapModel class

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Test.Model
{
    public class CevapModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        Cevap _cevap;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public CevapModel()
        {
            _cevap = new Cevap();
        }

        public CevapModel(Cevap cevap)
        {
            _cevap = cevap;
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _cevap.Id; }
            set
            {
                _cevap.Id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public int SoruId
        {
            get { return _cevap.SoruId; }
            set
            {
                _cevap.SoruId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SoruId");
            }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _cevap.Text; }
            set
            {
                _cevap.Text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public int Puan
        {
            get { return _cevap.Puan; }
            set
            {
                _cevap.Puan = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Puan");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestSonucuModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Test.Model
{
    public class TestSonucuModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        TestSonucu _testSonucu;
        SoruModel _soru;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public TestSonucuModel()
        {
            _testSonucu = new TestSonucu();
        }

        public TestSonucuModel(TestSonucu  testSonucu)
        {
            _testSonucu = testSonucu;
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _testSonucu.Id; }
            set
            {
                _testSonucu.Id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public int TestId
        {
            get { return _testSonucu.TestId; }
            set
            {
                _testSonucu.TestId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TestId");
            }
        }

        public int SoruId
        {
            get { return _testSonucu.SoruId; }
            set
            {
                _testSonucu.SoruId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SoruId");
            }
        }

        public SoruModel Soru 
        {
            get { return _soru; }
            set
            {
                _soru = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Soru");
            }
        }

        public int CevapId
        {
            get { return _testSonucu.CevapId; }
            set
            {
                _testSonucu.CevapId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CevapId");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator TestSonucu(TestSonucuModel t)
        {
            return t._testSonucu;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: where is `CevapId` defined?

Comment: its in testsonucu class which is used as observablecollection in test class

Comment: You bind `ItemsSource` to `TestSonucuCollection`. Am I right assuming that is it a collection of `TestSonucu` class which defines `CevapId` property?

Comment: Right. DataGrids ItemSource is bound to TestSonucuCollection. And CevapId is defined as integer in TestSonucu class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you said, `CevapId` is a property of `TestSonucu` class which is the view model behind each row of your `DataGrid` you don't need to change binding context in this case as it will be set to instance of `TestSonucu` class

```
<ListBox ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding Soru.CevapCollection}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Text" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CevapId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

also `SelectedValuePath`should be just `Id`, in the same way as you specify `DisplayMemberPath` which means it will take `Text` property of each `CevapCollection` item for display and `Id` property as value

Comment: Thanks. I tried. It's not working. I think because ItemsSource="{Binding Soru.CevapCollection} the SelectedValue looks at Cevap class which is in CevapCollection.

Comment: Is `Soru.CevapCollection` also part of `TestSonucu` class, as is `CevapId`? Does class behind each item of `CevapCollection` have `Id` and `Text` properties?

Comment: does it display items in the `ListBox` fine?

Comment: Yes. It works fine. I select Item for each listbox and when I try to save TestSonucu.CevapId is always 0.

Comment: can you try with `SelectedValue="{Binding CevapId, Mode=TwoWay}`?

Comment: Can you update your question with `TestSonucu` and `Cevap` class? At least the relevant parts.

Comment: I updated my question with CevapModel and TestSonucu classes. If you need other source I can provide it.

Comment: check my updated answer, but basically set `UpdateSourceTrigger` as well